# Are there differences in Test plans for an agile model and a traditional model?

Tags: agile, testing, waterfall, safe

Are there differences in in-sprint Test plans for an agile model and a traditional model?

Is there any best practices to follow for in-sprint test plans?

Answer (score 7):

My in-Sprint testplans always try to cover the area's defined in [Brian Maricks](http://exampler.com/) described [Agile testing quadrants](http://lisacrispin.com/2011/11/08/using-the-agile-testing-quadrants/).
We look at each area at the beginning of the story and defined what effort we are going to put into it, but also if it is relavant for this story. Afterwards we create sub-tasks if needed.

[image]

Agile:

- Focus is on test automation: https://less.works/less/technical-excellence/test-automation.html
- And thinking about testing: https://less.works/less/technical-excellence/thinking-about-testing.html

Waterfall:

- Focus is on release tests plans
- And often manual tested scripting

Other reads:

- Agile Testing: A Practical Guide for Testers and Agile Teams http://agiletester.ca/agile-testing/

Comment: You can also abstract your tests a little higher - use your user stories, business logic/acceptance criteria, and the idea of feature tours to create high-level testing scenarios.